# import() equivalent of import { something } from 'somewhere';

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I've got a file that exports few components that can be imported easily via

```
import { component1, component2 } from './components'
```

However now need to load them asynchronously and webpack allows us to split files into nice chunks using `import()` but I can't figure out if I can `import()` just a single component from `./components`. Alternative would be to place them into separate files, but wanted to check if it is possible via import() first.

Comment: you want to import one component either component1 or component2 from components correct ?

Comment: @MayankShukla yes, if possible it being split into separate file by webpack using `import()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `import()` does give you all exports by default, you can use destructuring to pick the imports you want:

```
import("./components")
    .then(({ component1 }) => {
        console.log(component1);
    });
```

Bundlers should be able to apply tree shaking against this code and determine that only `component1` is used - however I'm not entirely sure if the current version of Webpack does this. It will definitely create a separate chunk for `./components` at the very least.